# PyImport_Import segfault

Tags: python, c++, h5py

I am calling a single python module with a single function from a C++ application. I am getting a stack trace. I isolated it to the "import h5py" line in the python module. If I run this module and function inside the interpreter, everything is fine. Also, all other imports work. If I remove the "import h5py" and comment the code that uses it, then load the module and call the function from c++, everything works.

Also made a test.py and sure enough if I do this import and load the module in C++, it has the same result.

Has anyone seen something like this before? Is there a way to get around it because I really need to use h5py in my python module and need to call the module from our C++ application.

```
Killing process on sync signal: 6, Aborted                                                          
BEGIN stack trace                                                                                   
0: /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x346620f500]                                                          
1: /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x3465e328a5]                                                    
2: /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175) [0x3465e34085]                                                     
3: /opt/gs/lib/libhdf5.so.8(H5check_version+0x13d) [0x2b8c62611e5d]                                 
4: /opt/gs/epd-7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/h5f.so(inith5f+0x19c1) [0x2b8c8df11481]         
5: /opt/gs/epd-7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(_PyImport_LoadDynamicModule+0xc2) [0x2b8c61c78312]       
6: /opt/gs/epd-7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xed290) [0x2b8c61c76290]                               
7: /opt/gs/epd-7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xed531) [0x2b8c61c76531]                               
8: /opt/gs/epd-7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyImport_ImportModuleLevel+0x2be) [0x2b8c61c7756e]       
9: /opt/gs/epd-7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xd447d) [0x2b8c61c5d47d]                               
10: /opt/gs/epd-7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x68) [0x2b8c61bcef28]                    
11: /opt/gs/epd-7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x56) [0x2b8c61c5d9a6]    
12: /opt/gs/epd-7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x28b8) [0x2b8c61c60f08]             
13: /opt/gs/epd-7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x8d2) [0x2b8c61c65c12]               
14: /opt/gs/epd-7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x32) [0x2b8c61c65c62]                  
15: /opt/gs/epd-7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx+0xc2) [0x2b8c61c74c02]        
16: /opt/gs/epd-7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xec1ce) [0x2b8c61c751ce]                              
17: /opt/gs/epd-7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xeda8d) [0x2b8c61c76a8d]                              
18: /opt/gs/epd-7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xed290) [0x2b8c61c76290]                              
19: /opt/gs/epd-7.3/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xed764) [0x2b8c61c76764]                              
END stack trace
```

Comment: It looks like `H5check_version()` causes the abort. In that case, the documentation [here](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.6/RM_H5.html#Library-VersCheck) explains the error.

Comment: It is indeed C++ using h5 version 8 and python trying to import h5 version 7.  Trying to figure out solution with the linking.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but a possible workaround I used in the past: instead of calling `PyImport_Import()`, or before calling it, run

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import h5py");
```

If this succeeds, it will load h5py in sys.modules, and subsequent import will simply fetch the module in this dictionary.

Comment: That was a great idea, unfortunately for myself it produces the same error.